# JAVA (Android) bitwise operator on strings

Tags: java, android, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am getting mad, i need to create a token using this operator

PHP

```
a = "hello";
b = "world";
token = a | b;
```

well i need create the same in java [android] but i ever get error.
I  alredy try to:
- cast the 2 strings  to long but obvisuly i get an error on casting
- cast the 2 string in BitSet
- cast the 2 strings in Bit Array
but the final result was ever an error.
Someone can suggest me some tips please ?

Comment: I really don't understand. Are you trying to concatenate strings?

Comment: What should be the result of such operation?

Comment: What language are you using? You say PHP in the question, but it's tagged java and the code looks a little java-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to perform a bitwise operation on strings(which performs a bitwise operation on ASCII values of characters of these string in PHP). There is no such operator for `String` in Java, but you can do it using `BitSet`:

```
public String or(String a, String b) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final String charsetName = "US-ASCII";
    BitSet aBitSet = BitSet.valueOf(a.getBytes(charsetName));
    aBitSet.or(BitSet.valueOf(b.getBytes(charsetName)));
    return new String(aBitSet.toByteArray(), Charset.forName(charsetName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sotirios said, you are probably(?) trying to concatenate strings. If that's the case, then `String token=a+b;` should do the job. Again, it's unclear what you ask.. You might want to take a look at the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).